# Creating hyperlink with relative path in related standalone table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, relates, hyperlink

I have a polygon feature class which has a related table (1:n Relationship) containing the relative path of pdf documents in a field. Using the Info-Tool to click in a polygon in ArcMap 10.7 I can see the related table but I would also like to define the field "URL" as a hyperlink which would open the pdf document.

Is this possible?

I cannot find a way to configure the field of this related table to be a hyperlink.

The URL field contains the relative path to the pdf file without a network drive letter e.g directoryname/filename.pdf. the path is not contained with quotations. The relative path is not recognised as a hyperlink. Why is this?

Comment: You asked this question over 6 years ago and you didn't remember! :)

Comment: The answer provided does not answer my question. I need to know why the relative hyperlink doesn't work.

Comment: I would say even after 6 years nothing has changed and this indicates ArcMap does support relative hyperlinks in related tables, they need to be full path. A limitation of the software? I've not tried it in Pro yet.